# How can I remove @everyone in user roles? (Discord.py)

Tags: python, list, discord, discord.py, roles

I'm currently updating my userinfo command. But I still have a problem which i don't know how to fix. So here is my question how can I remove @everyone from the roles (you can see what I mean in the picture).

[image]

Code:

```
roles = [role for role in member.roles]
embed.add_field(name=f'Roles ({len(roles)}):', value="".join(
    [role.mention + "|" for role in roles]), inline=False)
```

Code Image:
[image]

I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always skip the first role which is `@everyone` like this.

```py
roles = [role for role in member.roles[1:]]
embed.add_field(name=f'Roles ({len(roles)}):', 
                value="".join([role.mention + "|" for role in roles]), 
                inline=False)
```